# EventLoop lifecycle duration in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-loop

**How long it will take Event Loop to finish full sycle in millis?**

I tried to google some queries , well, most results are about for/while loops and how should I calculate their runtime or just bunch of articles about EventLoop e.t.c.

Here some of my google search queries:

[how long it takes event loop to finish cycle](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20long%20it%20takes%20event%20loop%20to%20finish%20cycle) 
[node.js eventloop lifecycle duration](https://www.google.com/search?q=node.js%20eventloop%20lifecycle%20duration)

If somone may help me with my investigation , it will so interesting to investigate with you about this topic in comments

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0 might help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.